# How can I control white balance?

Tags: ios, camera

Every other digital camera I've used has a white balance control. I can't imagine a camera without one, since fundamentally the camera can't know what the "correct" white balance is without this human input.

Where is it in the iOS camera?

Comment: Computer 'devices' are getting pretty good at this these days, unless you're in an unusual environment, like a night club. Even on my real camera, I use auto-WB most of the time. If I need absolute precision I use a Passport... but that's getting a tad fussy for a snap from a phone. Humans, by comparison, are quite poor at judging WB - given the 2-slider structure, most will get it wrong. Clicking a grey-point & letting the computer work it out is usually far closer to accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White balance on the iPhone using the default Camera app is set automatically so you can't change it during or before you take the picture.

You can adjust it after the fact or you can use a 3rd party app that has white balance controls.

Answer (score 2):

The native iOS Camera app doesn't have this functionality.

Apps such as [Camera+ Legacy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camera-legacy/id329670577?mt=8) and [Camera+ 2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1313580627?mt=8) do have much more functionality. *

See [this site](https://iphonephotographyschool.com/best-camera-app-for-iphone/) for more info.

<sub>* Disclaimer: I'm a satisfied user of Camera+ Legacy and Camera+ 2, and I am in no way financially or otherwise connected with [LateNite Apps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/latenite-apps/id325758143).</sub>